# setState variable using a different name

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
bool isCollapsed;
bool isClosed;

void myFunc(bool isDone){
  if (condition) {
    setState(() => isDone = true);
  }
}

...

    myFunc(isCollapsed);  // somewhere in the code

...

    myFunc(isClosed);  // somewhere in the code
```

Basically I want to have one function for two state variables, so I'm trying to pass the state variable into the function. But that obviously does not work. I've heard there is no variable representation in Dart web or Flutter allowed (only Dart server VM), I've found no workaround myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible.

There is no way in Dart to do such a thing. The only potential workaround would be to use `dart:mirror`, but it is disabled in Flutter.

But you could change the prototype of your function to take closure used to modify the variable:

```dart
void myFunc(bool value, ValueChanged<bool> valueChanged) {
  if (foo) {
    setState(() => valueChanged(true));
  }
}


myFunc(isCollapsed, (value) => isCollapsed = value);

myFunc(isClosed, (value) => isClosed = value);
```